# Cannot save a pyspark word2vec model

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to save a trained pyspark `word2vec` in local, however this is resulting in an error - `Mkdirs failed to create`

```
model.write().overwrite().save("word2vec.model")
```

> 22/08/31 12:56:24 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 421.0
> (TID 11440) (100.66.40.74 executor 98): java.io.IOException: Mkdirs
> failed to create
> file:/home/jovyan/_git/notebooks/word2vec.model/metadata/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_202208311256242380698786646139780_0477_m_000000_0
> (exists=false, cwd=file:/opt/spark/work-dir)  at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:458)

The command does create a folder `word2vec.model`, but eventually fails. What can be the possible issue here?